# Why exactly does peaking of magnetization current occur in a transformer?

Tags: current, transformer, harmonics, magnetic-flux

Initially assuming that the input current is sinusoidal.

In a practical transformer, flux \$\phi\$ produced in the primary is not linearly proportional to the current \$I\$ through it. Due to saturation, the flux flattens

[image]

It's said that this flattening implies the presence of a dominant 3rd harmonic in addition to the fundamental

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Why does the presence of the third harmonic *in the flux*, *alter the current* (by adding a third harmonic out of phase by a 180\$^{\circ}\$)?
2. Why is it out of phase?

Comment: Are those homework questions that you have to answer?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Initially assuming that the input current is sinusoidal.*

and

> *Why does the presence of the third harmonic in the flux, alter the
>   current (by adding a third harmonic out of phase by a 180∘)?*

That's the bottom line - no matter what the flux does (in terms of non-linearity), the current is sinusoidal by definition.

However, if the winding were driven by a sine wave voltage then that's a different story and, current can appear very oddly affected by the diminishing flux at higher peak levels: -

[image]

GIF from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Power_Transformer_Over-Excitation.gif).

---

## Reason

In a normal inductor this formula applies \$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$

This gives us the sine-cosine relationship between voltage and current but, only if inductance is unchanging. As the core saturates, inductance drops dramatically and this, in turn, leads to a much greater \$\frac{di}{dt}\$.

Then, knowing\$^1\$ that the definition of inductance per turn is \$\dfrac{\Phi}{I}\$, if \$L\$ decreases and \$I\$ increases, then flux remains unaffected.

---

\$^1\$ We are taught that \$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ and this is taken from Faraday's law: \$V = N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$.

So, if we equate them: \$\dfrac{L}{N} = \dfrac{d\Phi}{di}\$ or, inductance per turn equals flux per amp.

Comment: I don't get it... What exactly happens when I apply a sinusoidal voltage to the primary?

Comment: If the voltage is low then you get a sinusoidal current. As the voltage rises the flux in the core saturates and you get a non-linear rise in current hence, the magnetization current looks very non-sinusoidal.

Comment: what is the animation depicting, the flux seems to be sinusoidal

Comment: The flux is sinusoidal for an applied sinewave of voltage  - this is because the current rises dramatically during extremes of saturation and forces the flux to be higher.

Comment: If current induces flux, and voltage causes current, shouldn't the current be sinusoidal, with a flattened flux like the first image? Why does current "become" non sinusoidal (with a dominant 3rd harmonic) to make flux sinusoidal?

Comment: Thank you for your patience